# Secure connection failed using apache2

Tags: ssl, connection, certificate, apache2

I want to connect to my own website (I have an ipython notebook server in localhost) through 443 port using apache2 (SSL connection). Besides, i would like to force a group of clients to authenticate using certificates(provided by an enterprise called REDIRIS to my Institution).

First, do i have to take two different certificates, one for the SSL connection (created by openssl), and the new one to force the clients to authenticate or only one to do the whole process? I think i'm too messed with this. This is my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com

   SSLEngine On
   SSLVerifyClient require
   SSLVerifyDepth 1
   # The CA certificate to authenticate the clients
   SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/cacert.pem"

   #own certificate for SSL connection
   SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/power.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/power.key

   # Access to my ipython server
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
   ProxyPassReverse /  http://127.0.0.1:8888/

   ProxyPass /api/kernels/ ws://127.0.0.1:8888/api/kernels/
   ProxyPassReverse /api/kernels/ ws://127.0.0.1:8888/api/kernels/

</VirtualHost>
```

I've imported the REDIRIS certificate in all browsers and when i try to connect to my website it requires the certificate but when i click accept always appears "secure connection failed".

I prove all options and always have problems. Does anyone help me to solve my doubts? Thanks ;)

Comment: Yesterday, it worked just upgrading  ipython notebook version: sudo pip install ipython[notebook] --upgrade